# Symfony2 "The option Required does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a `FormType` class called `BookType`. The method for generating the form is:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('required'=>$this->searchForm))
        ->add('author', 'text', array('required'=>$this->searchForm))
        ->add('genre', 'text', array('required'=>$this->searchForm));

    if(!$this->searchForm) {
        $builder
            ->add('picture', 'text', array('required' => false));
    }

    $builder
        ->add('description', 'text', array('required'=>$this->searchForm))
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('required'=>$this->searchForm))
    ;
}
```

However, whenever I try to access this with the following code:

```
$book = new Book();
$form = $this->createForm(
    new BookType(true),
    $book,
    [
        'action'=> $request->getUri()
    ]
);
```

I am seeing the following error message:

> The option "required" does not exist. Known options are: "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "disabled", "label", "translation_domain", "validation_groups".

As far as I am aware from the various tutorials I have read, this should be a completely valid parameter. Am I wrong here?

Comment: One of the fields can't have the "required" option like Taalaibek M. said?

Answer (score 5):

I think error is occurring here:

```
->add('submit', 'submit', array('required'=>$this->searchForm));
```

Since `'submit'` field does not have `'required'` option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll have a look into this and mark this as correct if it turns out good.